# I am trying to stand up a Eureka Registry service, however, the Eureka server stops immediately after start

Tags: java, spring, netflix-eureka

I am trying to stand up a spring cloud Eureka Server at my local machine by following instruction from Spring cloud website, however, the server was shutdown right after started, see below log files.

Here is the log file:

```
2018-07-16 11:23:15.313  INFO 10792 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2018-07-16 11:23:15.320  INFO 10792 --- [      Thread-12] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : Setting the eureka configuration..
2018-07-16 11:23:15.322  INFO 10792 --- [      Thread-12] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : Eureka data center value eureka.datacenter is not set, defaulting to default
2018-07-16 11:23:15.322  INFO 10792 --- [      Thread-12] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : Eureka environment value eureka.environment is not set, defaulting to test
2018-07-16 11:23:15.347  INFO 10792 --- [      Thread-12] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : isAws returned false
2018-07-16 11:23:15.349  INFO 10792 --- [      Thread-12] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : Initialized server context
2018-07-16 11:23:15.350  INFO 10792 --- [      Thread-12] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl    : Got 1 instances from neighboring DS node
2018-07-16 11:23:15.350  INFO 10792 --- [      Thread-12] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl    : Renew threshold is: 1
2018-07-16 11:23:15.351  INFO 10792 --- [      Thread-12] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl    : Changing status to UP
2018-07-16 11:23:15.399  INFO 10792 --- [           main] c.c.E.EurekaServiceApplicationTests      : Started EurekaServiceApplicationTests in 10.859 seconds (JVM running for 13.307)
2018-07-16 11:23:15.435  INFO 10792 --- [      Thread-12] e.s.EurekaServerInitializerConfiguration : Started Eureka Server
2018-07-16 11:23:15.728  INFO 10792 --- [      Thread-13] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@72209d93: startup date [Mon Jul 16 11:23:07 EDT 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6326d182
2018-07-16 11:23:15.735  INFO 10792 --- [      Thread-13] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Unregistering application EurekaService with eureka with status DOWN
2018-07-16 11:23:15.740  INFO 10792 --- [      Thread-13] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
2018-07-16 11:23:15.743  INFO 10792 --- [      Thread-13] c.n.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext    : Shutting down ...
2018-07-16 11:23:15.748  INFO 10792 --- [      Thread-13] c.n.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext    : Shut down
2018-07-16 11:23:15.752  INFO 10792 --- [      Thread-13] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Shutting down DiscoveryClient ...
2018-07-16 11:23:15.752  INFO 10792 --- [      Thread-13] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Completed shut down of DiscoveryClient
```

Here is the POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.cyanne</groupId>
    <artifactId>EurekaService</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>EurekaService</name>
    <description>Eureka Service for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>10</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Here is my class file:

```
   package com.cyanne.EurekaService;

   import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
   import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
   import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
   import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;
   import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

   @SpringBootApplication
   @EnableEurekaServer

   public class EurekaServiceApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(EurekaServiceApplication.class, args);
   }
  }
```

Here is my application Property file:
spring.application.name=EurekaService

```
   eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone:http://localhost:9091/eureka/
   server.port=9091
   eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
   eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

Comment: You aren't starting your server you are running a test... `2018-07-16 11:23:15.399  INFO 10792 --- [           main] c.c.E.EurekaServiceApplicationTests      : Started EurekaServiceApplicationTests in 10.859 seconds (JVM running for 13.307)`. That is probably the default test which only starts the context. Instead run the actual application NOT the test.

Comment: Thanks. That is the problem -- it by default running a test. Run the actual app is fine now.